# Is it possible to mock API responses with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am considering writing an automation test with Selenium WebDriver for a sign up page. In order to not over populate the database, I would have to mock the response given by the sign up API.

Is this possible?

Comment: you would need to ask the dev to add the this feature before it can work. Also, you if you have access to the database, you can write db query script which will just delete email addresses with specific string in it. You can run the script at day end to stop it over populating your database

Comment: Absolutely **nothing** to do with Selenium. Selenium automates browser. The mocking and database layer is relating to the programming language you are using.

Comment: @Arran you should post it as an answer really.